# F# NativePtr.stackalloc slower then C# stackalloc - Decompiled Code Included

Tags: c#, f#, stack, unmanaged-memory

Continuing my F# performance testing. For some more background see here:

[f# NativePtr.stackalloc in Struct Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423640/f-nativeptr-stackalloc-in-struct-constructor)

[F# NativePtr.stackalloc Unexpected Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471757/f-nativeptr-stackalloc-unexpected-stack-overflow)

Now I've got stack arrays working in F#. However, for some reason the equivalent C# is approximately 50x faster. I've included the ILSpy decompiled versions below and it appears only 1 line is really different (inside stackAlloc).

What's going on here? Is the unchecked arithmetic really responsible for this big difference? Not sure how I could test this??

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx

**F# Code**

```
#nowarn "9"

open Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop
open System
open System.Diagnostics    
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices        

[<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)>]
let stackAlloc x =
    let mutable ints:nativeptr<byte> = NativePtr.stackalloc x
    ()   

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv

    let size = 8192            
    let reps = 10000

    stackAlloc size // JIT
    let clock = Stopwatch()
    clock.Start()
    for i = 1 to reps do            
        stackAlloc size
    clock.Stop()

    let elapsed = clock.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
    let description = "F# NativePtr.stackalloc"
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} bytes, {2} reps): {3:#,##0.####}ms", description, size, reps, elapsed)

    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0
```

**C# Code**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CSharpLanguageFeatures
{
    class CSharpStackArray
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 8192;
            int reps = 10000;

            stackAlloc(size); // JIT
            Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
            clock.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            {
                stackAlloc(size);
            }
            clock.Stop();

            string elapsed = clock.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,##0.####");
            string description = "C# stackalloc";
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} bytes, {2} reps): {3:#,##0.####}ms", description, size, reps, elapsed);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public unsafe static void stackAlloc(int arraySize)
        {
            byte* pArr = stackalloc byte[arraySize];
        }
    }
}
```

**F# Version Decompiled**

```
using Microsoft.FSharp.Core;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Module)]
public static class FSharpStackArray
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public unsafe static void stackAlloc(int x)
    {
        IntPtr ints = stackalloc byte[x * sizeof(byte)];
    }

    [EntryPoint]
    public static int main(string[] argv)
    {
        PrintfFormat<FSharpFunc<string[], Unit>, TextWriter, Unit, Unit> format = new PrintfFormat<FSharpFunc<string[], Unit>, TextWriter, Unit, Unit, string[]>("%A");
        PrintfModule.PrintFormatLineToTextWriter<FSharpFunc<string[], Unit>>(Console.Out, format).Invoke(argv);
        FSharpStackArray.stackAlloc(8192);
        Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
        clock.Start();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10001; i++)
        {
            FSharpStackArray.stackAlloc(8192);
        }
        clock.Stop();
        double elapsed = clock.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} bytes, {2} reps): {3:#,##0.####}ms", "F# NativePtr.stackalloc", 8192, 10000, elapsed);
        ConsoleKeyInfo consoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**C# Version Decompiled**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CSharpLanguageFeatures
{
    internal class CSharpStackArray
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 8192;
            int reps = 10000;
            CSharpStackArray.stackAlloc(size);
            Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
            clock.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            {
                CSharpStackArray.stackAlloc(size);
            }
            clock.Stop();
            string elapsed = clock.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,##0.####");
            string description = "C# stackalloc";
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} bytes, {2} reps): {3:#,##0.####}ms", new object[]
            {
                description,
                size,
                reps,
                elapsed
            });
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public unsafe static void stackAlloc(int arraySize)
        {
            IntPtr arg_06_0 = stackalloc byte[checked(unchecked((UIntPtr)arraySize) * 1)];
        }
    }
}
```

**F# Version IL - Byte Allocation**

```
.method public static 
    void stackAlloc (
        int32 x
    ) cil managed noinlining 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] native int ints
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: sizeof [mscorlib]System.Byte
    IL_0008: mul
    IL_0009: localloc
    IL_000b: stloc.0
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method FSharpStackArray::stackAlloc
```

**C# Version IL - Byte Allocation**

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void stackAlloc (
        int32 arraySize
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2094
    // Code size 8 (0x8)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: conv.u
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0003: mul.ovf.un
    IL_0004: localloc
    IL_0006: pop
    IL_0007: ret
} // end of method CSharpStackArray::stackAlloc
```

**Updated F# IL - IntPtr Allocation**

```
.method public static 
    void stackAlloc (
        int32 x
    ) cil managed noinlining 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] native int ints
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: sizeof [mscorlib]System.IntPtr
    IL_0008: mul
    IL_0009: localloc
    IL_000b: stloc.0
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method FSharpStackArray::stackAlloc
```

**Updated C# IL - IntPtr Allocation**

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void stackAlloc (
        int32 arraySize
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2415
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: conv.u
    IL_0002: sizeof [mscorlib]System.IntPtr
    IL_0008: mul.ovf.un
    IL_0009: localloc
    IL_000b: pop
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method CSharpStackArray::stackAlloc
```

Comment: Can you show the actual IL of both `stackAlloc` methods?

Comment: Hmmm, possibly the sizeof [mscorlib]System.Byte or the nop? There's also a nop in the loop?

Comment: `sizeof` definitely plays a part, but I think much more significant is the `mul`.

Comment: Try it with a type that would be different on different architectures - say, the `intptr` itself. It seems that the C# compiler optimizes this calculation by using the knowledge that `sizeof(byte)` is always `1`.

Comment: Changing to an IntPtr allocation makes the C# version take about 2x longer then originally. It makes the F# version take 10x longer then originally.

Comment: Now I see two differences: `mul` vs. `mul.ovf.un` (the latter is faster) and `stloc.0` vs. `pop` at the end. You can't do anything about the former, but try the latter: tweak the C# code to make sure the result isn't discarded.

Comment: Also: are you sure that the two run with the same "enable optimization" setting?

Comment: It turned out I wasn't. The C# version was running under 32 bit. When I changed it to x64 the performance halved - IL remained unchanged inside the stackAlloc method though. Are there other settings apart from "optimise code" that I need to check?

Comment: I noted that the `F#` was tagged with `noinline`. Added it to the `C#` version but no great difference. In this case one would really benefit of seeing the exact x64 code that is executed. Unfortunately this is made more difficult by that the JIT:er changes the JIT:ed code depending on whether a debugger is attached or not. One could generate a crash inside the loop and take the memory dump and check that code using windebug.

Comment: The noinline came out of a previous stack overflow I was getting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471757/f-nativeptr-stackalloc-unexpected-stack-overflow. The F# compiler was inlining the stackAlloc method inside the loop so the stack pointer wouldn't get reset.

Comment: I started working directly with the IL Assembly and compiling using ilasm.exe, and after adding the .locals.init to the C# version it causes the performance to match that of F#. Interestingly I cannot get the F# IL Assembly to run after I compile it manually (in another directory). I keep getting "Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Console.WriteLine(System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object)'. at Program.main(String[] argv)"

Comment: Thank you both very much for the help. Not sure on the etiquette here regarding answers and upvoting etc - can't upvote a comment.  Do I now "Answer My Question", even though the answer came about through your generous assistance?

Comment: @Researcher: You wrote an excellent question, and I think that writing an answer to your own question and accepting it is very much warranted as a service to the community, given that it has been 3 weeks since and no one took on it. Please do if you have time and desire! It is certainly harder to follow through the discussion in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help with this.

The answer was that the C# compiler was not storing the pointer as a local. This was because the allocated memory was never needed. The lack of "sizeof" and the differing "mul" gave the C# another slight edge.

**F# Assembler - Differences Are Commented**

```
.method public static 
    void stackAlloc (
        int32 x
    ) cil managed noinlining 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init ( //***** Not in C# Version *****//
        [0] native int ints
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: sizeof [mscorlib]System.Byte //***** C# just uses "1" *****//
    IL_0008: mul //***** C# uses "mul.ovf.un" *****//
    IL_0009: localloc
    IL_000b: stloc.0 //***** Not in C# Version *****//
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method FSharpStackArray::stackAlloc
```

**C# Assembler - Differences Are Commented**

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void stackAlloc (
        int32 arraySize
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2094
    // Code size 8 (0x8)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: conv.u
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.1 //***** F# uses sizeof [mscorlib]System.Byte *****//
    IL_0003: mul.ovf.un //***** F# uses "mul" *****//
    IL_0004: localloc
    IL_0006: pop
    IL_0007: ret
} // end of method CSharpStackArray::stackAlloc
```

This exercise has taught me a few things:

1. Compilers perform a lot of optimization. Apparently identical high level code in different languages can result in quite different sets of machine instructions.
2. When benchmarking dotnet languages you can read the Intermediate Assembly to really see whats going on. Use ILSpy for this.
3. You can modify and compile Intermediate Assembly using ilasm.exe.
4. the C# compiler is doing a better job here of removing unnecessary code. Once you set every byte in the allocated memory, the performance becomes very similar as expected initially.

**Final F# Code**

```
#nowarn "9"

open Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop
open System
open System.Diagnostics    
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices        

[<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)>]
let stackAlloc x =
    let mutable bytes:nativeptr<byte> = NativePtr.stackalloc x
    for i = 0 to (x - 1) do
        NativePtr.set bytes i (byte i)
    ()   

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv

    let size = 8192            
    let reps = 10000

    stackAlloc size // JIT
    let clock = Stopwatch()
    clock.Start()
    for i = 1 to reps do            
        stackAlloc size
    clock.Stop()

    let elapsed = clock.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
    let description = "F# NativePtr.stackalloc"
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} bytes, {2} reps): {3:#,##0.####}ms", description, size, reps, elapsed)

    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0
```

**Final C# Code**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CSharpStackArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 8192;
            int reps = 10000;

            stackAlloc(size); // JIT
            Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
            clock.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            {
                stackAlloc(size);
            }
            clock.Stop();

            string elapsed = clock.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,##0.####");
            string description = "C# stackalloc";
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} bytes, {2} reps): {3:#,##0.####}ms", description, size, reps, elapsed);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public unsafe static void stackAlloc(int arraySize)
        {
            byte* pArr = stackalloc byte[arraySize];
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            {
                pArr[i] = (byte)i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```